# Не переключается раскладка на русскую в root shell ubuntu в режиме восстановления

Tags: ubuntu, bash

При входе в консоль в режиме восстановления, не переключается консоль на русский язык. 
На ubuntu 19.04

Если запускать оболочку то всё нормально.

Получается переключение раскладки отключено по умолчанию в режиме восстановления?

Comment: А зачем в режиме восстановления отличный от английского язык? Можно и руками инициировать загрузку шрифтов и переключателя клавиатуры, но зачем?

Comment: Я как я перейду в папку с русским названием?

Comment: В режиме *восстановления* язык, отличный от английского, не нужен, если не начудили при установке системы.

Comment: У меня вопрос в другом. А не в том нужен или не нужен какой то язык.

Comment: Ну я же писал, если очень нужно, то запустите соответствующие сервисы самостоятельно. А так, все вопросы к системе инициализации (upstart, systemd, etc).

Comment: А какие сервисы и как нужно запустить самостоятельно?

Comment: Вы точно читали мой первый комментарий? Там ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: В первом комментарии нет ответа на вопрос. Есть размытая рекомендация. Которая саму проблему не решает.

Comment: Решение проблем — это, наверное, к фрилансерам, а так вы ничему не научитесь, если не будете прикладывать самостоятельных усилий. Ваш вопрос не содержит: а) конкретики, б) описания шагов, которые **вы** предприняли для решения проблемы. Я вам дал направления для поиска, вот потрудитесь немного.

Comment: Я и не пытаюсь этому научиться. На этом сайте система вопрос - ответ. Чтобы через поиск быстро найти решение проблемы, а не тратить время на её изучение. Всему научиться невозможно. Времени не хватит. В этом я вижу большую ценность этого сайта.

Comment: Помогают только тому, кто хотя бы сам прикладывает усилия. Удачи!

Comment: А тут и не надо кому то помогать. Есть проблема - вопрос, в ответах специалист может описать почему это происходит в чем причина и как это поправить. Тогда другие люди сталкивающиеся с аналогичным, сразу увидят подробное описание проблемы. А не кучу комментариев и потенциально опасного кода или команд, от пытающегося решить проблему не специалиста.